# Remove GMT+530(Indian standard Time) without changing current time in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am displaying current day,month,date,year and time like this

```
Mon Oct 24 2016 17:09:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)​​​​​​​
```

but i need to display like this

`Mon Oct 24 2016 17:09:25`
my code in javascript:

```
var timestamp = new Date();
editor.insertHtml( 'The current date and time is: ' + timestamp.toString());
```

How can i do this please can anyone tell me how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: `timestamp.toString().split('+')[0]`

Comment: Where you are doing `timestamp.toString()` replace it with `timestamp.toString().split('+')[0]`

Comment: Hi, `Mon Oct 24 2016 17:27:06 GMT` it came like this but i don't need to display `GMT` also please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to add a library, you should use `moment.js`

```js
console.log(moment().format('ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If not, a small work around

```js
var d = new Date().toString();
var index = d.lastIndexOf(':') +3
console.log(d.substring(0, index))
```

**Note:** moment approach is more preferred

Comment: Thank you it will work fine. but i need `10/24/2016` format is it possible

Comment: You can achieve it as `moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

This is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timestamp = new Date();

console.log(
  timestamp.toString().split('GMT')
)
// Mon Oct 25 2021 17:56:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
```

the Output will be Mon Oct 25 2021 17:55:02

Answer (score 0):

```js
let today = new Date();
today = today.toString();
today = today.split('G')[0];
console.log(today);
```